# Not able to create ec2 instance with terraform with instance tagging with minimal IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam

I have the below iam policy to create ec2 instances which has tag "project:test-project":

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "ec2:RegisterImage",
            "ec2:CreateImage",
            "ec2:CopyImage",
            "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
            "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
            "ec2:DetachVolume",
            "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/project": "test-project"
            },
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "aws:TagKeys": [
                    "project"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

But when I create an ec2 instance with below terraform resource:

```
resource "aws_instance" "test_instance" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = var.instance_machine_type
  key_name = var.key_name
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.test_profile.name
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id_1
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"

  tags = {
    Name = "test-instance"
    Environment = var.environment
    project = "test-project"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("./test.pem")}"
      host        = "${self.public_dns}"
    }
    
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "run-collector.sh"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/run-collector.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /home/ubuntu/run-collector.sh",
      "sudo /home/ubuntu/run-collector.sh",
    ]
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb",
      "sudo dpkg -i -E ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb",
      "sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/home/ubuntu/log_agent_config.json -s"
    ]
  }
}
```

I get below error:

```
"DecodedMessage": "{\"allowed\":false,\"explicitDeny\":false,\"matchedStatements\":{\"items\":[]},\"failures\":{\"items\":[]},\"context\":{\"principal\":{\"id\":\"AIDA3GKLMDVKBZJXS7XUH\",\"name\":\"terraform_test_user\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:iam::769494097236:user/terraform_test_user\"},\"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\",\"resource\":\"arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:769494097236:key-pair/odm\",\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ap-south-1\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Service\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Resource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"key-pair/odm\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Account\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"769494097236\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Type\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"key-pair\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:KeyPairType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"rsa\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ap-south-1\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:ARN\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:769494097236:key-pair/odm\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"false\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:KeyPairName\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"odm\"}]}}]}}}"
```

I can't get why tagging is not working proerly with terraform, while when I remove the condition from policy i am able to create instance.
My terraform version is v1.0.4 with registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.53.0 aws provider

Comment: "remove the condition from policy " - which condition? FIrst, second or both?

Comment: @Marcin when i remove both condiotions